# How can I restore my audio to menu bar?

Tags: 13.10, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm having problems with my headphones not working all of a sudden on Ubuntu 13.10.  I tried fixing it by changing a bunch of files, removing alsa-mixer and pulseaudio and reinstalling.  Still haven't got audio in my headphones, but what is worse (I think), I can't see the audio widget in the menu bar at the top of the screen.  How can I restore that?  I thought reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio and rebooting would bring it back, but it hasn't.

See screenshot, to see that there is no audio icon at the top right[image]

Comment: Worked. Should I close? @Donarsson

Comment: We will flag this as duplicate for you.